# angular-hotkeys , how to override comb?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one page which has simply save button and i set alt+s for that.

```
hotkeys.bindTo($scope).add({
    combo: ['alt+s'],
    description: 'Collect Payments',
    callback: function() {
        $scope.collectPayment();
    }
});
```

Below that there is one add button. when add button is presed one model is opened.
On that model also have save button and i have to set alt+s for that also.

```
hotkeys.bindTo($scope).add({
    combo: ['alt+s'],
    description: 'Save Form',
    callback: function() {
        $scope.saveForm();
    }
});
```

How it isa possible ?
i tryed but main page key is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunatly i find answer of this.

When open model just delete all combs and initialize model combs.

and when close model reinitialize that main page combs.